# Swiperjs autoplay not working correctly on mobile (Safari + Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, safari, swiper.js

on site https://vitad.io/ we have on second section SwiperJS with autoplay. On desktop it is working fine, but on mobile, if I am scrolling through section with autoplay, is still resetting to first slide. I tried a lot of things (include up/downgrade swiperjs version). On mobile version on desktop (via responsive design) is working completely fine too.

Here is my html:

```
                <figure class="swiper block-logos">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_viactiv.svg')}}" alt="Logo Viactiv" height="52">
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_dkv.svg')}}" alt="Logo DKV" height="42">
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_aok.svg')}}" alt="Logo AOK" height="58">
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_securvita.svg')}}" alt="Logo Securvita" height="52">
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_bkk_sbh.svg')}}" alt="Logo BKK SBH" height="60">
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="swiper-slide">
                        <img src="{{asset('imgs/web/logo_bkk_pfalz.svg')}}" alt="Logo BKK Pfalz" height="48">
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </figure>
```

Here is my swiperJS code:

```
        var swiperListLogos = new Swiper(".block-logos", {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 32,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        loop: true,
        speed: 2500,
        updateOnWindowResize: false,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 0, //it happens with every speed
            disableOnInteraction: false
        },
        breakpoints: {
            767: {
                slidesPerView: 6,
                centeredSlides: false,
                spaceBetween: 60,
            },
            1199: {
                slidesPerView: 7,   
            }
        }
    });
```